# writing a for loop that appends a column by joining every iteration - r

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, left-join, assign

I need to join data to a tibble (or dataframe) iteratively such that the tibble grows by one column every time the loop is executed.

Let bin_list be the identifier that the join is executed on:

```
bin_list<-c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
```

and let the following three tibbles be joined one at a time:

```
hour_1<-(tibble(bin_list=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), rain=c(0,0,.25,0,0,.25,0,0,0,0,.25)))
hour_2<-(tibble(bin_list=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), rain=c(0,0,.25,0,0,0,0,0,.25,0,.25)))
hour_3<-(tibble(bin_list=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), rain=c(0,0,.25,0,0,.25,0,0,.5,0,.25)))
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to produce:

```
final<- tibble(bin_list=c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), hour_1=c(0,0,.25,0,0,0,0,.25), hour_2=c(0,0,0,0,0,.25,0,.25), hour_3=c(0,0,.25,0,0,.5,0,.25))
```

been messing around with 'for', 'left_join', and 'assign' but can't crack it.  I know there is a more efficient way to join these hours (nesting left joins maybe), but I'm dealing with moderate sized data.

The bin_list is ~75,000 rows and each hour_i is stored as a .txt file ~1.5 million rows.  What I"m trying to accomplish is call hour_1, left_join to bin_list, assign it in env, call hour 2, left_join to hour_1 that's already joined bin_list, assign it in env, call hour 3....

for
left_join
assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just do a series of `left_join()`s with a loop:

```r
library(dplyr)
bin_list <- data.frame(bin_list = c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))
hour_1<-(tibble(bin_list=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), rain=c(0,0,.25,0,0,.25,0,0,0,0,.25)))
hour_2<-(tibble(bin_list=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), rain=c(0,0,.25,0,0,0,0,0,.25,0,.25)))
hour_3<-(tibble(bin_list=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), rain=c(0,0,.25,0,0,.25,0,0,.5,0,.25)))

## gets names of all objects that start with hours_ and then have some number of digits afterward. 
hrs <- grep("hour_\\d+", ls(), value=TRUE)

## initialize final with bin_list
final <- bin_list
for(h in hrs){
final <- left_join(final, 
                   setNames(get(h), c("bin_list", h)))
}
#> Joining with `by = join_by(bin_list)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(bin_list)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(bin_list)`
final
#>   bin_list hour_1 hour_2 hour_3
#> 1        6   0.00   0.00   0.00
#> 2        7   0.00   0.00   0.00
#> 3        8   0.25   0.00   0.25
#> 4        9   0.00   0.00   0.00
#> 5       10   0.00   0.00   0.00
#> 6       11   0.00   0.25   0.50
#> 7       12   0.00   0.00   0.00
#> 8       13   0.25   0.25   0.25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(vroom) ## for fast, lazy loading of text files

## assuming your text files are called "hour_1.txt" etc:
source_files <- sprintf('hour_%s.txt', 1:3)

main_bin_list <- 6:13

cbind(main_bin_list,
      source_files |>
      map(~ vroom(.x) |>
            filter(bin_list %in% main_bin_list) |>
            select(rain)       
          ) |>
      reduce(cbind) |>
      setNames(nm = source_files)
      )
```

output:

```
  main_bin_list hour_1 hour_2 hour_3
1             6   0.00   0.00   0.00
2             7   0.00   0.00   0.00
3             8   0.25   0.00   0.25
## ...
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow this through and it looks quite a nice way of doing it - where do you get `tibble_names` from for the `setNames()`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That was a remainder from my earlier local version which processed the workspace tibbles (`hour_1` ...) instead of files.